# Obtaining the value of a Cognos Insight Tuple using Report Studio

Tags: cognos

Not sure if this is the place for Cognos Insight report building syntax Qs but ill give it a go. Im trying to convert a tuple data item to a 'member' or 'measure'. I need to do this so i can nest that tuple within another so i can use it as part of a graph.

Data Item:
[x]-tuple([x],[y])

Is there a way to get the value of this tuple? something like the following? value([x]-tuple([x],[y]))